# Can I call stopSelf() in Service.onStartCommand?

Tags: android, android-service

There are some conditions where my service could be attempted to be started when it should not be. In cases like this is it bad form to call `stopSelf()` while inside a `onStartCommand()` method? If so what is the best way to handle such a situation? Any resources will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

> is it bad form to call stopSelf() while inside a onStartCommand() method?

Off the top of my head, I can't think of why that would be a problem.

`stopSelf()`, like a lot of stuff in Android, has no immediate effect. It puts a message on the message queue processed by the main application thread. The actual work of stopping the service will not even begin until sometime after `onStartCommand()` has returned.

Comment: I figured it wasn't but I wasn't entirely sure of the inner workings of the Service class and calling a function that stops it from starting before it's even finished some start related event seems like it could result some unwanted behavior depending on how it was designed.

Comment: @SpencerRuport: `stopSelf()`, like a lot of stuff in Android, has no immediate effect. It puts a message on the message queue processed by the main application thread. The actual work of stopping the service will not even begin until sometime after `onStartCommand()` has returned.

Comment: As a follow-up question, what would be the appropriate return value having just called `stopSelf()`?

Comment: @MarkCarter: Presumably `START_NOT_STICKY`.